# Gradle fatJar: I get class not found error if my main class is in test folder, works fine if main class is in src/main/java

Tags: gradle, fatjar

I am using fatJar to create Jar. The jar works fine if my class with main function is in src/main/java.

I get class not found error if my class is in src/test/java.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Put your `main` class in `src/main/java` then?